# WooCommerce product built with Gravity Forms need weight added to product before adding to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom product built with Gravity forms conditional logic. Weights are added in a separate plugin to be used for shipping. Shipping is multi-carrier. The problem we are having is that the weights are added at the cart level, but the live rates shipping plugins we have tried checks for weights coming from the product rather than at the cart. Is there a way to programmatically add the weights to the product before it is added to the cart?

Our code to add the weights to the product is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'kj_after_add_cart_item', 10, 3 );
function kj_after_add_cart_item( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if ( isset($cart_item['weight']['new']) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_weight($cart_item['weight']['new']);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the plugin developers response on how the weight is found:

> "We retrieve the weight from WooCommerce Product object. Ex: $product->get_weight()
> When WooCommerce calculate_shipping() is triggered the plugin gets the Cart/Checkout Packages from which we get the Product Object."

Is there a way to add the weights to the product where it can be found at $product->get_weight() so we can use a live rates shipping plugin?
Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?